# How to resize a window with a certain key-combo + mouse move? (like Alt+F8 in Linux) Not click and drag

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, resize, window-resize

In a C# winform app, I'm trying to implement some of Linux window manager features.
I already did a lot of stuff, but right now, I'm trying to do the re-sizing part, where you press a certain combo at a window, then move your mouse to the right/left, the width of the window increases to the right/left, move it diagonally, the window will increase in both directions.

Now I already know how to register the hotkeys, get/set mouse cursor pos, move a window, etc. All in winapi.

The thing that I can't seem to get that much, is how can I increase the window's, say width, in one direction? if I normally increase it, it will span in both directions. I gave this a thought, and I think that: the window will increase in both directions, but if we want to just increase it's width to the right, we keep re-positioning/moving it at it's start point, so that the left side of it will remain fixed, will the right one will span.

What is the right and easy way to do this? Am I right about my guess?

And please note that I don't just want this to work only in my form, but on any window.

Any C++/C#/Winapi code would help.

Any ideas/thoughts of some sort would also be great.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know what Alt+F8 does, but just capture the form's mouse move, then check the key-shift state. To resize, you just specify the form's Left, Top, Bottom, Right, Width, Height, or Location properties, depending on what you want. You do not need to call any WinAPI functions.

Comment: I don't want this on my form, I want this to work on other windows, like open folders, calc, firefox, mediaplayer, etc.

Comment: You stated "winform app". You need to change question. Regardless, the technique will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Any Windows window:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> - brings up the standard Windows menu
- <kbd>S</kbd> - selects Size
- Arrow keys (Or Mouse) - Resizes the window
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> - commits the operation

Comment: I know about this. But it's really slow, and I don't need to resize it with arrow keys or whatever, I need to use the mouse movement.

Comment: Fair enough.  FYI, after your first arrow-key hit, the mouse can be used to complete the resize operation.

Comment: OK, faster, but still not as fast. But this means that this property could be reached programmatically I think, maybe there's a way to fool it so that it first moves with the mouse...